# Convert geodatabase categorized style to QGIS style

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, style

I'm using ArcMap 10.2.2 and QGIS 2.6.1. Brighton. 
I set up a geodatabase in ArcMap and used subtypes while I was digitilizing geometries.

As I'm opening the geodatabase in QGIS, I noticed that the programm is showing me all geometries in one color, and I'm not able to under categorize the styles.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While QGIS is able to work with the data in geodatabases, it has a different concept of styles.

You can easily switch the renderer to a [categorized renderer](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/classification.html#basic-fa-classifying-nominal-data) and define the symbology you want.

Sidenote: please update to a more recent version of QGIS. 2.6.1 is way over end of life. You will find many more features and much more stability in a newer version of QGIS.

Comment: I would like to underline the sidenote : you definitively need to update your version ! QGIS 2.6 is way too old now. There's so much powerful features and bugs that have evolved since :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately i am not allowed to update to a new version of QGIS (I am doing a course and the schools computers are off boundaries when it comes to changing the software). However, i was not able to used the categorzied renderer, all subtypes from ArcMap stay in one color. Maybe its due to the old version of QGIS.

Comment: Too bad, indeed. But you can still install QGIS on a personal computer if you have one :)

Comment: Are you able to see the subtypes in the attribute table inside QGIS?

Comment: I'm only able to see the category-numbers, but not able to "force" QGIS to kategorize these as different styles

Comment: if you see the numbers in the attribute table you are able to categorize by them. Make sure you choose the proper column and then click classify. And talk to the IT staff of your department and show them [the roadmap](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/roadmap.html#release-schedule) that doesn't even mention 2.6 any longer ;)

Comment: Thats what i thought, i assumed that if I can see the categories in the attribute table, then there must be a way to classify them. I have chosen the right colunm (if i take a different column where there are no subtypes then it works perfectly!). I'll just continue trying out....

Comment: This sounds like a bug which was fixed in newer versions of QGIS - it's specific to categorizing using a column from a geodatabase. The only solution is to upgrade to 2.14 or above, or switch to a different data format.

Comment: Solution found! In my version, it was not possible to categorize the subtypes, i however asked my tutor (who has the newest Version of QGIS to try it out and it worked). For me, I still had to find a solution: the only thing that worked was to export the layer (within QGIS) as a shape-file and reopen it. Then I was able to categorize. Thanks for all the help!!!